# JSON error keeps coming in random order while executing python code which gets data from internet

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

Below is the code.. importers is another python file where I have placed all the necessary codes.. I am taking input in variable "abd" which is being passed in URL parameter and the data is getting loaded into CSV.. that's the actual expectation

But at times, it doesn't work and gives the error even if I am providing the correct value for "abd" parameter. JSON throws some errors and I am technically not a sound person. Please help with what should I do.. pasting the error below the code.

---

### "Code"

```
import os
from importers import *

abd = input('Name the stock: ')
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol='+abd
print(url)

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'}


session1 = requests.Session()
request = session1.get(url, headers=headers)
cookies = dict(request.cookies)
response = session1.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).json()
rawdata3 = pd.DataFrame(response)
rawop3 = pd.DataFrame(rawdata3['filtered']['data']).fillna(0)
rawop3.to_csv('StockOC.csv', index=False)
results = pd.read_csv('StockOC.csv')
```

---

### ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OptionChain\codes\StockOC.py", line 15, in <module>
    response = session1.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).json()
  File "C:\Users\VC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 917, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Resource not found</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #e8e8e8;">
  <div style="font-size: 32px; padding: 50px 25px; text-align: center;">
    Resource not found
  </div>
</body>
</html>
: 0
```

Comment: If the issue occurs only some times, are you certain that your get request gives correct response?

Comment: Yes, other time it works perfectly fine. @matszwecja

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The above code gives the error as shown below in random fashion. Sometimes it works properly and sometimes it shows error, even if abd parameter is provided correct input.

Comment: The html in the traceback looks liek your request would be returning a status_code 404. The api will likely return different json or none at all. After your request put in a check. Eg if request.status_code == 200: parse else: handle/log the failure

Comment: I tried that.. and seems like it is giving 401 many times, probably that website might be blacklisting the IP.. any better to get secured connection ?